# Does paper blunt scissors?

Tags: physics

It is widely [believed](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Science/Question1104234.html) that paper blunts scissors. But it is difficult to imagine why paper should be more harmful than say hair.

**Is paper really any worse for scissors than hair, or any other object?**

Comment: I thought this was going to be a Rock-Paper-Scissors question.

Comment: Any type of cutting will tend to dull the blades of the scissors, factors will be types of materials (cutting and scissors), how he blades are made, and how often they are used. Much of the paper out there has many chemicals added to it such as clay, which can be abrasive on scissors causing the to wear a bit faster.

Answer (score 24):

**Yes.** Unless you're only using them to cut paper. Then you probably won't notice for decades.

From the provided link...

> 1. All females say that paper blunts scissors
> 2. All men say 'Impossible'.

This part is straight forward....

1. The females are using the scissors as a tool in a specific
   application; cutting hair, fabric, or anything that requires accuracy.
2. The men just want to cut whatever happens to need cutting (paper,
   cardboard, duct-tape, tin, wire, thin rocks, etc.) with whatever
   tool is close at hand. Any foul-ups in accuracy can be fixed with
   more duct-tape.

The cheapest pair of children's safety scissors will cut paper and, as many parents know full well, they will also cut hair (and most fabrics). **Very poorly.**

> Scissors cut things! Don't mix up scissors that you use for fabric
> with scissors that you use to cut paper because fabric scissors are a
> lot better when they are super sharp and paper dulls scissors. You
> won't notice it too much on paper because you can still cut paper with
> really dull scissors, but when you go back to cutting fabric, you'll
> have a sad face! [-source](http://www.thingiverse.com/tool:71)
>
> Do not cut anything else other than fabric or thread with your
> favorite sewing scissors/shears. Especially paper dulls blades very
> fast ==> there is nothing more frustrating and tiring to your hand
> than using dull scissors. Non-sharp scissors can damage fabric. Your
> cutting accuracy will also be affected if the scissors/shears are
> trying to chew through the fabric rather than cut through it.
> *...snip...* trusted sharpening companies to do this as once messed up scissors will only be good for paper cutting jobs after. [-source](http://zsuzsybee.hubpages.com/hub/Sewing-Scissors-Scissors-Basics-for-Every-Sewing-Task)

"*Super sharp*" is key. Fabric and hair are thin "floppy" fibers that bend out of the way easily.

The steel of the scissors is of course very hard. However, it is important to note:

**A sharp edge is a thin edge.**

And it is the edge that is easily blunted by the minerals found in most paper.

> There are four popular minerals used in paper filling and coating:
> kaolin clay, calcium carbonate (available as ground or precipitated),
> titanium dioxide and talc. Both titanium dioxide and talc, however,
> are consumed in small quantities for special applications where
> extreme whiteness and opacity, or pitch control are required. Hence,
> the workhorse minerals employed in the paper industry today are
> precipitated and ground calcium carbonates and kaolin clay.
> [-source](http://www.specialtyminerals.com/paper/why-are-minerals-used-in-paper/why-is-pcc-preferred-in-paper/)

- Barium Sulfate and Precipitated Calcium Carbonate (typical fillers)
  have a [Mohs-Hardness](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/387714/Mohs-hardness) of **~3.0**.
- Titanium Dioxide (used to increase opacity & brightness) has a
  hardness of **~5.75**.
- A copper penny has a hardness of **~3.2**.

**Cutting up copper pennies will most assuredly dull scissors.**  *(The progression from 3 to 4 on the Mohs scale reflects an increase in hardness of approximately 25 percent. [-source](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/387714/Mohs-hardness))*

---

### The Bottom Line

From a guy that sharpens stuff for a living...

> **Caution!    Tools I Sharpen Will Be Extremely Sharp! They Must Be Handled With Awareness.**
>
> If you are uncomfortable using **extremely sharp scissors or shears you
> can easily reduce their sharpness.** If your shears are stylist, barber
> or grooming shears **simply cut on a paper towel** until the sharpness is
> reduced to a level you are comfortable with. If your shears are for
> cutting fabric or other materials **make several cuts on a piece of 20
> pound copier paper** until you are comfortable. Razors or surgical
> scissors should never be reduced in sharpness. They should be
> maintained to extreme sharpness in relation to their intended
> procedure. [-source](https://www.fastsharp.com/Shears___Scissors.html)

---

**Postscript**

My wife and I have a simple agreement...

- I don't cut paper (or anything else) with her fabric shears and she
  doesn't cut up flagstones with my chainsaw.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be worth the spectacle (and price of a new chain) to watch the Mrs chew up flag stones with a chainsaw? You sharpen things for a living and your name is Rusty? Oh the irony (rusty irony)

Comment: -1 for casual sexism for no purpose, and the poor quality of most of the references. The comparison to copper pennies makes no sense to me. (Are the hard particles small enough that the paper will shear along the cellulose fibres instead, making them irrelevant? Possibly not, but there doesn't seem to be anything here say shows that.)

Comment: @Oddthinking Did you find the quote [here](https://www.fastsharp.com/Shears___Scissors.html) convincing (from a company that sharpens scissors)? "If you are uncomfortable using extremely sharp scissors or shears you can easily reduce their sharpness. If your shears are stylist, barber or grooming shears simply cut on a paper towel until the sharpness is reduced to a level you are comfortable with. If your shears are for cutting fabric or other materials make several cuts on a piece of 20 pound copier paper until you are comfortable."

Comment: +1 for "Any foul-ups in accuracy can be fixed with more duct-tape." despite the fact that this answer really is not valid.

Comment: @Avrohom: Is it right? Maybe. Probably. It seems plausible. Is it *convincing*? No, not without them providing details of how they know this to be true. Experts get things wrong. People who claim to be experts get things wrong. Companies who claim to employ experts get things wrong.

Comment: @Oddthinking I looked long and hard for a peer reviewed study on the matter an came up with nothing (I'll keep looking).

Comment: Interesting notes on paper additives.  I assume that cardboard would be even worse and would dull a knife with enough cutting.

Comment: I totally forgot that this question was here, and was going to ask it myself. When I looked at this answer (having forgotten that I commented on it) I asked myself whether the hardness scale was relevant. I am willing to drop 6 feet onto sand, but I won't drop 6 feet onto limestone rock. Do they have the same hardness?

Comment: @Oddthinking I was, oddly, just thinking about this and yes, hardness would be a major factor. The harder the material the better it will "keep an edge". Steel is great for making sharp stuff because with some water, a hammer and fire you can easily manipulate its hardness to suit your needs. Like making axe heads hard so they'll stay sharp cutting timber all day and swords flexible to prevent snapping if caught between ribs:) Ceramic bladed scissors would certainly standup much better than steel to the hard stuff found in most papers.

Comment: @Rusty: Hardness of the scissor blades? Yes absolutely! But what about the hardness of the calcium carbonate, for example. If you replaced all the finely-ground calcium carbonate with finely-ground diamonds, would the paper be harder on the scissors? Or would it continue to break at the weak points? (i.e. presumably the cellulose and the gaps between the fibres, but my material science knowledge is lacking.)